# Cant compile SharpSNMPLib - the target "clean" does not exist in the project

Tags: visual-studio-2017, sharp-snmp

I'm trying to build SharpSNMPLib in a standard install of visual studio 2017 but as the title implies it wont compile

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   MSB4057 The target "Clean" does not exist in the project.   SharpSnmpLib    C:\stuff\sharpsnmplib-master\SharpSnmpLib\SharpSnmpLib.csproj   1
```

Any idea what I need to do to get it compiling ? I've got .net framework 4.6 installed. When I look at the project properties, the version of .net is just a grey box which I can't edit, so I think thats a clue that it might be missing the version of .net it was built for.

[image: Project Properties dialog]

I've already run the bat file "prepare.bat" (and a few others lol!).

Comment: You have to use latest VS2017 (15.7 for example) with .NET Core 2.0 SDK. Otherwise, the projects won't be properly recognized by the IDE.

Comment: Thank you. Yes I am on 15.7.5, the latest. This is Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2017. .Net framework says 4.7.03056. Its not flagging for any upgrades in the notifications flag so I think its up to date. Thats why I think I'm missing a framework or two.

Comment: Oh, regarding ,NET core 2,0, I don't think I have that BUT, I need the encryption stuff AES and DES for SNMP v3 to work, and therefore I don't think it will work with .NET Core ??

Comment: I managed to get it compiling by creating a new project linked to .net 4.6.2 and pulling all the CS files into it. Its working for snmpget now, so now I'm just stuck on how to use mib names instead of OIDs... will update when its working